# Forgotten Pattern/Pass Lock on Android

Tags: recovery-mode, usb-debugging, password, locked-out, pattern-lock

How to remove pattern/pass lock from an android device if the USB Debugging is off and Recovery Mode is inaccessible and it doesn't have a Gmail account?

It's a Chinese Tablet

Name & Model: Eken E902
Build Number: astar_m900-eng 4.4.2 KVT49L 20160322 test-keys
Kernel Version: 3.4.39
Firmware is exdroid4.4.2_r2-a33-v2.1
O/S version is Kitkat 4.4..2

Comment: Add more detail:, phone model, OS version

Comment: I've added the information

Comment: Did you try resetting it? With buttons combo (Volume up + Power button)

Comment: These always have a factory reset option somewhere, finding it can be difficult since it is often poorly, if at all, documented. Try various key combinations when powering on, the bad part of it is some of these require specific timing, like hold PWR+VOL UP+VOL DN until it vibrates then release PWR while holding other keys (just an example).  If you can come up with any kind of model or manufacturer, we may be able to narrow it down more.

Comment: Your first look should go to our [locked-out tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info). As this is a frequently asked question here, we've setup some first-aid there. Please check it out, then come back and let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck – or answer your question if you were able to solve your issue.

Comment: The full info has been added. Some of the tablets are able to boot in recovery others are not when (PWR + HOME) these are the keys however some are not although they're same model and kind. Also if I boot in recovery is it possible to remove patter/pass or I should do factory reset for that?